# Multiple cURL actions, same session

Tags: php, curl

First of all I'm aware of curl_multi_init but it doesn't exactly do what I need, to my knowledge.

Im downloading files behind a login, so

a) Need to login
b) Download image(s)

Here is what I currently have

```
$login_url = 'https://us.test.com/Member/Login';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$this->username.'&password='.$this->userpass.'&signin=1&login_referer=none&remember_me=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/cookie.txt');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
curl_exec($ch);

//Grab and Write the image
$image = file_get_contents($image_url); 
$f = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/uploads/'.$id.'.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);  


curl_close($ch);
```

Anything helps, much appreciated.

Comment: You're getting the auth cookie via curl, but then you're not using them to download the image. Have you tried downloading it via curl using the cookie file from the login?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, just added session ID into cURL.  But a quick and dirty way is

$download_str = 'wget -O '. $save . $id . '.jpg --cookies=off --header "Cookie: PHPSESSID=' . $session_id . '" ' . $image_url;

shell_exec($download_str);